# How to delete uploaded image on amazon s3 server?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading few images on s3 server and storing the link in local DB using my android app. Now, if i am deleting a particular image link from local DB, i also want to remove the same image from s3 server.

Is it possible to delete image from s3 server using android app?

If yes, please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code works for me. folderPath is something like "topDir/secondDir/"

```
void deleteObjectsInFolder(String bucketName, String folderPath) {


 for (S3ObjectSummary file : s3.listObjects(bucketName, folderPath).getObjectSummaries()){
  s3.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
}
}
```

Comment: If you have them stored in SQLite you can store the object key you used to put the object in S3 and then as you are deleting rows, you can send a deleteObject request with the key.  Keep in mind your app may be offline and you will want to have a table or marker for images that need to be deleted, but could not be when the user deleted the local image.